# Accuracy drops in Tensorflow-Onnx-Tensorrt

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, tensorrt

I have a tensorflow trained model and tested at tensorflow with accuracy achieved 95%.

Tensorflow model is converted to ONNX and converted to TensorRT.
TensorRT engine runs with 16-bit precision.
In TensorRT, accuracy drops to 75%. Even with kTF32, accuracy is still 75%.
Tested same images for both tests and same input size.

Where should I look at for this accuracy drop? The only difference is I do batch inference in TensorRT, but not in Tensorflow.

Images are read using OpenCV for both Tensorflow and TensorRT.

Can the accuracy drop in conversion from Tensorflow to ONNX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the issue. Tensorflow did normalization to input image by multiplying 1/255.0. But in tensorrt normalization, it is 1- x/255.0. That is the issue. Now I have same accuracy.